# Can a .Net Framework 4.6.2 project generate a .Net Core DLL?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-4.6.2

Is it possible for a .Net Framework 4.6.2 project to use System.Reflection.Emit to create a .Net Core or .Net Standard DLL file?  What I have now is a project that generates a .Net Framework 4.0 DLL file.  Can I change some setting somewhere so that the generated DLL file uses .Net Core or .Net Standard instead?

Edit: Here's an example.  I got the following code from [this page that covers the System.Reflection.Emit library](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/reflection-and-reflection-emit-in-C-Sharp/).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        AssemblyName am = new AssemblyName();
        am.Name = "TestAsm";
        AssemblyBuilder ab = ad.DefineDynamicAssembly(am, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("testmod", "TestAsm.exe");
        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("mytype", TypeAttributes.Public);
        MethodBuilder metb = tb.DefineMethod("hi", MethodAttributes.Public |
        MethodAttributes.Static, null, null);
        ab.SetEntryPoint(metb);

        ILGenerator il = metb.GetILGenerator();
        il.EmitWriteLine("Hello World");
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        tb.CreateType();
        ab.Save("TestAsm.exe");
    }
```

When I run this code, it generates TestAsm.exe.  When I open TestAsm.exe in my decompiler (JetBrains dotPeek), it shows that TestAsm.exe is "**msil, .Net Framework v4.0, Debug**"

How do I change this?  My project is a .Net 4.6.2 project, so the generated EXE is not based on the generating project's framework version.

Comment: I don't believe you can cross-compile with `Emit`... And 4.0 *is* the version of framework for 4.6.2 (you can check it by looking at properties of any of the system.* assemblies).